# How can I sort strings into the correct alphabetical order using only if statements from my code?

Tags: java

I was wondering if anyone could assist me with trying to sort three string values into the correct alphabetical order using only if statements?

From my understanding the operator choice that I'm using is for integer values and not strings. Therefore, what operator can I use instead that applies for strings? Incase someone says skip if statements all together and use arrays I can't, if statements only.

**MY CODE**

```
    String p= "Matt";
    String m ="Jack";
    String o ="Sam";

   if (( p <= m ) && ( m <= o ) )
    {
        System.out.println("");
   } 
   else if (( p <= m) && ( m <= o ) )
   {
        System.out.println("");
   }
   else if (( o <= p ) && ( p <= m ) )
   {
        System.out.println("");
   }
   else if (( o <= m ) && ( m <= p ) )
   {
        System.out.println("");
   }
   else if (( m <= p ) && ( p <= o ) )
   {
        System.out.println("");
   }
   else
   {
        System.out.println("");
   }
```

[Error I'm getting in BlueJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu0LM.png)

Comment: Strings can't be compared using `<` etc. - instead they implement the `Comparable` interface and thus provide a `compareTo(otherString)` method. Use that, e.g. instead of `p <= m` use `p.compareTo(m) <= 0` ( a negative value would mean `p < m`, 0 would mean `p == m` and a positive value would mean `p > m` - so for `p <= m` we can use either `... <= 0` or `... < 1`).

Comment: @Thomas I will look into this thanks for the helpful response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to compare strings with <= which is not operable on strings, that's why you get the error stating bad operand type.

You should use string1.compareTo(string2) method to compare two strings. It returns 0 when two strings are equal, negative number if string1 < string2 and positive number if string1 > string2.

Given that, you should do something like this:

```
String p= "Matt";
String m ="Jack";
String o ="Sam";

if (( p.compareTo(m) <= 0 ) && ( m.compareTo(o) <= 0 ) )
{
    System.out.println("");
} 
else if (( p.compareTo(m) <= 0 ) && ( m.compareTo(o) <= 0 ) )
{
    System.out.println("");
}
else if (( o.compareTo(p) <= 0 ) && ( p.compareTo(m) <= 0 ) )
{
    System.out.println("");
}
else if (( o.compareTo(m) <= 0 ) && ( m.compareTo(p) <= 0 ) )
{
    System.out.println("");
}
else if (( m.compareTo(p) <= 0 ) && ( p.compareTo(o) <= 0 ) )
{
    System.out.println("");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
    if (p.compareTo(m) <= 0) {
        if (m.compareTo(o) <= 0) {
            System.out.println(p);
            System.out.println(m);
            System.out.println(o);
        } else if (p.compareTo(o) <= 0) {
            System.out.println(p);
            System.out.println(o);
            System.out.println(m);
        } else {
            System.out.println(o);
            System.out.println(p);
            System.out.println(m);
        }
    } else {
        if (p.compareTo(o) <= 0) {
            System.out.println(m);
            System.out.println(p);
            System.out.println(o);
        } else if (m.compareTo(o) <= 0) {
            System.out.println(m);
            System.out.println(o);
            System.out.println(p);
        } else {
            System.out.println(o);
            System.out.println(m);
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
```